# How to make icons (photos) responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive

I'd like to know how I can make 4 icons become two rows of 2 icons when I smaller the screen size. Also the color gradient restarts when I'm testing it on smaller screens. I'm still a beginner so I'm pretty new at this and didn't really find it so I'd really appreciate the help. Thanks on advance:

### [image: Website]

[image: Non-responsive smaller screen]

My code goes like this atm:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One);

html{
  height: 100%;
}

body{
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
  background: #2C3E50;  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top, #4CA1AF, #2C3E50);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #4CA1AF, #2C3E50); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */


}

.container{
  margin: auto;
}


h1{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 47px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-shadow: #533d4a 1px 1px, #533d4a 2px 2px, #533d4a 3px 3px, #533d4a 4px 4px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
}


.title{
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-5deg);
  display: block;
  margin-left:50%;
}











.icon{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
  transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 35px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  /*background: #007991;  /* fallback for old browsers */
  /*background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #78ffd6, #007991);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  /*background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #78ffd6, #007991); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}

.icon:hover, .icon:focus, .icon:active {
  box-shadow: 0 50px 50px -50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 50);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}



.icontext{
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}



table {
    border-spacing: 60px;
    border-collapse: separate;
}








.contactbtn{
  margin-right: 15px;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 35px;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 12px 40px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;

  background: #007991;  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #78ffd6, #007991);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #78ffd6, #007991); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="display: block;">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Knowledge base</title>
  <href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      <script src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <!--Titel-->
  <section class="container">
  <h1>
    <br />
    <span class="title" >
       <label style="color:#e55643;">Burger</label><label style="color:#2b9f5e;">school</label>
    </span>
    <span class="title" style="color:#f1c83c;">afspraken</span>
  </h1>
</section>

<!--Icoontjes-->
<table align="center">
  <tr>
    <h1>
    <td><a href="afspraken.html"><img src="https://www.icloud.com/system/cloudos/17BHotfix5/cloudos_foundation/17BHotfix5/en-us/source/resources/images/app_icons/reminders_icon@2x.png" alt="" class="icon" style="height: 182px; width: 182px;"></a></td>
    <td><img src="https://www.icloud.com/system/cloudos/17BHotfix5/cloudos_foundation/17BHotfix5/en-us/source/resources/images/app_icons/fmf_icon@2x.png" alt="" class="icon"></td>
    <td><img src="controlcenter.png" class="icon"style="height: 180px width: 180px;"></td>
    <td><img src="Multitaks.png" class="icon"style="height: 180px width: 180px;"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td class="icontext">Afspraken</td>
      <td class="icontext">Situaties</td>
      <td class="icontext">Grenzen</td>
      <td class="icontext">Categoriëen</td>
  </tr>
</table>



<!--Contact-->
<input type="button" class="contactbtn" value="Contact">




</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

look up for media queries:

```
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp
```

They're looking like this

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
body {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

}

and you can enter specific css for a specific size

Hope it will help you

/**EDIT**/
You are using tables to position your elements. Tables are not really usefull to use in responsive design. Maybe you can change your layout to a modern grid system like Bootstrap or stuff

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks for the info. I've heard of bootstrap but don't really now how to work with it and if I can still implement this into my webpage because I've already did all the other design without bootstrap...

Comment: Is your whole Homepage designed with tables? As i mentioned they are really badly supported in responsive. Bootstrap is only an example. But if you are building your Homepage with a div based grid it's way easier.

Comment: The answer above mine has a nice workaround for tables. But i want to be honest. I don't like table layouts for the mentioned reasons.

Comment: Only my icons and text beneath it are tables, could you please tell me how to change them to div based grids? Or is that too much work? I'm still a beginner actually so I don't really know the best way to make a responsive site...

Comment: http://codepen.io/oknoblich/pen/fvbFJ If you want to see pure css/html and no scss and haml. Go to the arrow down and choose "view compiled css", "view compiled html"

Comment: [Example grid](http://gridbyexample.com/examples/example1/) Is this a good example?

Comment: Also you can try this one http://www.simplegrid.io /*Its simple and for beginners and responsive*/ GL my friend

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/y4750e2f/) fiddle.

**CSS Updates:**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  td {
      float: left;
      margin-right:10px;
      width: 45%;
  }
  td:nth-child(3) {
      clear: left;
  }
  .icon{
    width:100%!important;
    height:100%!important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi bud, thanks for the help. The icons are devided in 2 rows with 2 icons now. But I got another problem now. The text stays under the icons while the text should stay under the icon where it belongs to.

Comment: Move names inside respective icons container. No need to use separate tr.